# Boost system 1.69.0 not header only?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-system

Boost system is a header only library since 1.69.0. However, linking against `libboost_filesystem.so.1.69.0` gives these linker errors:

```
ld: libboost_system.so.1.69.0, needed by libboost_filesystem.so.1.69.0, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
```

which suggest that I still need to link against `libboost_system.so`, even though it is supposedly header only. Do I need to set some special flags when building Boost itself to get a truly header only system library?

Comment: boost-system still has a stuc, so maybe not all dependent libraries were updated in bjam so that they don't link against the stub?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher, I think you are right: https://github.com/boostorg/filesystem/blob/develop/build/Jamfile.v2

Comment: I was just looking at the same file :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boost system is now indeed header-only, but provides a stub for backward compatibility with projects that require such a library.

> Boost.System is now header-only. A stub library is still built for compatibility, but linking to it is no longer necessary.

It may be that Boost FileSystem is not yet updated to remove the stub as indicated on line: https://github.com/boostorg/filesystem/blob/develop/build/Jamfile.v2#L29

Comment: Thank you, I've filed an issue on Github for this: https://github.com/boostorg/filesystem/issues/98