# Could not find the following Boost libraries: boost_system

Tags: c++, boost, build, cmake

I want to build this repository: https://github.com/reo7sp/tgbot-cpp.

It is an API for managing Telegram bots. The needed dependencies are openssl, zlib, boost. Curl is optional.

### How I installed libraries and cmake

**Boost was compiled with:**

```
bootstrap.bat
.\b2
```

and (since I do not know the difference; one compiles under boost/stage/lib; the second under boost/lib)

```
bjam install --prefix=D:/Programme/Boost/boost_1_69_0 --with-system --with-date_time --with-random link=static runtime-link=shared threading=multi
```

I added the required paths in system variables under path.

[environment variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I208y.png)

[Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wYW9.png)

### When trying to build with cmake I get the following error:

```
The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.16.27026.1
The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.16.27026.1
Check for working C compiler: D:/Programme (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe
Check for working C compiler: D:/Programme (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe -- works
Detecting C compiler ABI info
Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
Detecting C compile features
Detecting C compile features - done
Check for working CXX compiler: D:/Programme (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe
Check for working CXX compiler: D:/Programme (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe -- works
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
Detecting CXX compile features
Detecting CXX compile features - done
Looking for pthread.h
Looking for pthread.h - not found
Found Threads: TRUE  
Found ZLIB: D:/Programme (x86)/GnuWin32/lib/zlib.lib (found version "1.2.3") 
Found OpenSSL: optimized;D:/Programme/OpenSSL-Win64/lib/VC/libcrypto64MD.lib;debug;D:/Programme/OpenSSL-Win64/lib/VC/libcrypto64MDd.lib (found version "1.1.0j")  
Could NOT find CURL (missing: CURL_LIBRARY) (found version "7.63.0")
CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:62 (find_package):
  Policy CMP0074 is not set: find_package uses <PackageName>_ROOT variables.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0074" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  Environment variable Boost_ROOT is set to:

    D:\Programme\Boost\boost_1_69_0

  For compatibility, CMake is ignoring the variable.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Error at D:/Programme/CMake/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2100 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.69.0

  Boost include path: D:/Programme/Boost/boost_1_69_0/include/boost-1_69

  Could not find the following Boost libraries:

          boost_system

  No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the
  directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of
  Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:62 (find_package)


CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
CURL_LIBRARY
    linked by target "TgBot" in directory G:/Programmieren (C++)/Bibliotheken/tgbot-cpp-master

Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "G:/Programmieren (C++)/Bibliotheken/tgbot-cpp-master/BUILD/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "G:/Programmieren (C++)/Bibliotheken/tgbot-cpp-master/BUILD/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

It seems to me that everything except of Boost works. I know that there are several users with this problem like:

[Cmake doesn't find Boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808775/cmake-doesnt-find-boost)

[CMake with Boost could not find static libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20654959/cmake-with-boost-could-not-find-static-libraries)

[CMake with Boost library Windows 10 Library not found correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47936353/cmake-with-boost-library-windows-10-library-not-found-correctly)

### So, I did the suggested procedures:

```
SET(CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH ${CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH} "D:/Programme/Boost/boost_1_69_0")
SET(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH} "D:/Programme/Boost/boost_1_69_0/lib")

FIND_PACKAGE(Boost)
IF (Boost_FOUND)
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
    ADD_DEFINITIONS( "-DHAS_BOOST" )
ENDIF()
```

and

```
set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR D:/Programme/Boost/boost_1_69_0/lib)
```

Nothing worked. I have absolutely no clue what to do, for days desperately trying to figure out what to do without success. Please, help me.

Comment: Did you build boost yourself? There should be a stub boost-system though.

Comment: Yes, as described above. What do you mean with "stub boost-system"?

Comment: Boost system is now header only https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54184576/boost-system-1-69-0-not-header-only

Comment: Can you check that you have boost-system built, as expected?

Comment: Yes, it seems so: https://imgur.com/A1zdVzO

Comment: here: D:\Programme\Boost\boost_1_69_0\stage\lib

Comment: OK, so you obviously have a mistake in your setting, as you ask to look for /lib and not /stage/lib.

Comment: For `find_package(Boost)` there is nice debugging option - `Boost_DEBUG`. Enabling it (e.g. with `-DBoost_DEBUG=1` as `cmake` option) allows you to check, where the Boost libraries are **actually searched**.

Comment: Where do I need to put "-DBoost_DEBUG=1". I am quite a newbie.

Comment: You provide it at the command line, if you are calling CMake in the console 
_cmake <other cmake args> -DBoost_DEBUG=1_

Comment: I do not understand what exactly i have to type in in cmd. What do you meant with <other cmake args>? What arguments?

Comment: With which command do you build **your** project? If this is `cmake` executable (with some arguments), then add `-DBoost_DEBUG=1` to that arguments.

Comment: I always did it with Cmake GUI.

Comment: Then in CMake GUI add a variable named `Boost_DEBUG` of type STRING and assign 1 to its value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the same command to build and install Boost.

```
bjam install --prefix=D:/Programme/Boost/boost_1_69_0 --with-system --with-date_time --with-random link=static runtime-link=shared threading=multi
```

In windows, Boost creates another sub directory under include. It should be something like this.

```
D:/Programme/Boost/boost_1_69_0/include/boost-1_69
```

Move all files in `D:/Programme/Boost/boost_1_69_0/include/boost-1_69` to `D:/Programme/Boost/boost_1_69_0/include/`

(Move the contents up to one directory)

Now set the `BOOST_ROOT` in CMake project to `D:/Programme/Boost/boost_1_69_0`.

It should work now.

Comment: absolutely works! Thank you very much. It took like 20 hours for me to look for a solution..

Answer (score 1):

According to your comments, the location for Boost is `D:/Programme/Boost/boost_1_69_0/stage/lib`, but you set it to `D:/Programme/Boost/boost_1_69_0/lib`.

Anyway, Boost can be found if you set (usually manually, in the CMake UI rather than in the CMakeLists.txt file) `BOOST_ROOT` to `D:/Programme/Boost/boost_1_69_0` with `FIND_PACKAGE(Boost)`.

This will in turn set all the `Boost_*` variables that you need to use.

Comment: by default, Cmake looks for the boost libraries in stage/lib (i did not change anything manually): https://imgur.com/q5Tx3ug

Comment: after I have set "Boost_DIR" to "D:\Programme\Boost\boost_1_69_0" and click on "configure" cmake states again Boost_DIR --> "Boost_DIR-NOTFOUND": https://imgur.com/JQNWg1Y

Comment: Obviously something is wrong with either your install or your variables. This has always worked out of the box on any configuration I used.